# How do I remove search bar that isn't a widget?

Tags: themes, search

I'm a newby and don't have much knowledge of programming. My website is https://www.laraellisphotography.com I'm using the Divina theme and I can't figure out how to remove the search bar. I tried to see if it's a widget but it appears to be hardcoded into the theme. It shows up under the menu I put in. Can somebody explain to me in very specific terms how to fix this? I'm using a plugin called advanced code editor but I really don't know what I'm doing. I tried putting in a show: none phrase in around where I thought the programming was for the search in the css styles sheet but it didn't change anything. Thanks for any help you can give me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can that by css :

1. Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS
2. Paste this code AFTER all the contents

   **.main-navigation .menu-item-search {
            display: none;
       }**
3. Save

You can also do that by adding this code of line in the bottom most part of the functions.

1. Login to Dashboard
2. Go to Appearance -> Editor
3. Click Theme Functions at the right side
4. Add code at the last part after all the content

   ```
   remove_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'divina_add_search_box_to_divina_menu', 10, 2 );
   ```
5. Save.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You have no idea how much this little thing has been driving me crazy for weeks lol! The first solution with the code added into additional CSS you gave me did the trick! thanks again and have a great evening! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Questions about specific themes are best answered by their support page.

But, a general answer is to use your browsers Developer Tools to inspect that search element to find the element's class name. Then, add Additional CSS (usually via the Theme's Customization screens, althought there are plugins that do that), add this CSS (replacing the class name with what you found with the Developer tools):

```
.the_search_element_class_name {display:none !important;}
```

If the element has an ID, but no class, do this:

```
#the_search_element_id_name {display:none !important;}
```

And there you go!